# Installing Bootstrap 3 with concrete5.6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, concrete5

I'll preface my question with this - I'm not new to web development, but I am a total noob with concrete5. Still getting my head around the terminology like blocks and page types.

I need to build a responsive, mostly static site with concrete5.6 built on the bootstrap 3 grid system (upgrading to 5.7 isn't an option for this project). However it seems that 5.6 ships with bootstrap 2 out of the box - how can I upgrade this to bootstrap 3? I couldn't find any minimal bootstrap 3 themes for 5.6, is my best option here building my own theme?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "minimal" in this case but I would say you have to possibilities:
1- Use a bootstrap 2 theme, look how it's done and easily re-do it with bootstrap 3.
This one is free: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/bootswatch/

2- Or get a bootstrap 3 theme. I don't know if you will consider them minimal but they do exists. For instance:
THis one is free: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/casual/
This one is not free but seems very complete and not overly "designed": http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I think Nour gave a pretty accurate answer. It's also important to note that just because Concrete5 CMS is built on Bootstrap 2, doesn't mean your themes have to be. Your themes can implement no framework, or any framework such as foundation, bootstrap1/2/3/4/10. You decide what to include in your theme.

Concrete5 does a pretty good job prefacing its interface with a class so that it doesn't affect your styles. Likewise, your styles should also not be greedy. For example, if you wrap your entire markup in a div with a class called "my-website" - try prefacing your styles with that.

That said, and as Nour pointed out, there is a non-free theme for Bootstrap 3 which acts as a great boilerplate: http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/themes/bootstrap/

Comment: One thing to note is that Concrete 5.6 ships with an older jQuery version. When you are including the newest version of Bootstrap 3. You will get an error in the console that Bootstrap require a more recent version of jQuery.